# What is the difference between new Runnable and functional interface of type Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, functional-interface

When I create an `Observable` with a lambda for a `Runnable` the code will execute the `run` method on the schedule.  But if I create a new Runnable the code does not execute that schedule nothing happens?

The code that gets and uses the `Runnable`

```java
Observable<Usage> usageObservable = Observable.create(emitter -> {
  ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

  executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(createNewUsageListener(emitter), 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

});

ConnectableObservable<Usage> connectableObservable = usageObservable.share().publish();

connectableObservable.connect();
```

The code that works and executes in the `ScheduledExecutorService` schedule.

```java
private Runnable createNewUsageListener(ObservableEmitter<Usage> emitter) {
  return () -> {
    List<Usage> usages = getUpdates(rollDice(0, 5));
    if (usages != null) {
      emitUsageStats(emitter, usages);
    }
  };
}
```

This code appears to be the same code to me but it does not execute in the `ScheduledExecutorService`

```java
private Runnable createNewUsageListener(ObservableEmitter<Usage> emitter) {
  return new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      List<Usage> usages = getUpdates(rollDice(0, 5));
      if (usages != null) {
        emitUsageStats(emitter, usages);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Because it should work. Did you use a debugger or some logging to check if the `run()` method is executed?